# USB hardware disappears

Tags: usb, hard-drive, printing, external-hdd

I'm just going to use this for an example. I have a Western Digital Passport, external hard drive. I plug it into the USB port on my computer, it shows up immediately, I go through and browse, and move files back and forth, no problem. A few hour later and I go to move some more files over, and it has disappeared from the connected hardware list. For example, when you go to the "Computer" link that takes you to the page with all the storage media, ie..hard drives/cd/dvd drives, it is just no longer there. I have to unplug and replug so it will show up again. It's fine for another few hours, or sometimes a few days, then it disappears again, starting the process over again. Why does hardware plugged into the USB ports disappear like that? It's not just the hard drive, my printer, and an external DVD drive I have also do the same thing. I've had this happen to windows machines, different computers than I have now. So this problem is multiple OS's, and multiple machines, can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: This might could be related to some sleeping mechanism. Can you provide your /Var/log/syslog somehow

Comment: it happens when inserting the external hard-disk on windows also.

Comment: It might a power save option of the device. But access syslog under Ubuntu is much easier tan fuzzing around with Windows logging system